# How can i code a function that can read a text file and write into a list?

Tags: python, list, readfile

How can i code a function that can read a text file append it into a list 
thank in advance.
i tried this but it won't work .

```
def readdata (z):
x=[ ]
for dig in open(z).readlines():
    digx=dig.strip().split(" ")
    if len(dig) == 0:
        print 
        return 0

    else :
        return x.append(str(digx))
        print x
 readdata (r'C:\Users\Administrator\Coding\Python\Text\Day5\scores.txt')
```

Comment: In assembly, I presume.

Comment: What do you want in the list? A list entry per line?

Comment: What kind of list? I doubt I read "and doesn't call another function or code" right, as this means you want it to happen magically. Nothing happens magically in programming.

Comment: The negative votes reflect the fact that you should do some basic research before posting a question on StackExchange.  Read the FAQ and welcome to the community!

Comment: Also, a really good tip (if I say so myself!) Use pdb.set_trace() at the start of your script and walk through it.  You'll have to import pdb at the start.  You can read about pdb, or its more visual cousins such as pudb, winpdb, etc. online.

Answer (score 2):

This is a two-liner in Python

```
with open("myfile.txt") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
```

`lines` is then a list of the lines of the file.  Each will end with a '\n' (newline) character, except possibly the last line.

Comment: why not just `lines=list(file)` if you are just gonna store it in memory anyway there isnt much call for a generator

Comment: @JoranBeasley True!  I'm just in the habit of using generators because I rarely store intermediate results.  But yes, for the OP's question your suggestion is more concise.